# Validation Vs form control

Tags: excel, activex

My question wasn't at all specific but i wanted to gauge user insight, I was looking into building a excel / sql DashBoard which users can use based upon their credentials being within the sql table, but the first hitch i wanted to discuss is drop down boxes and what would be a better option, after data validation method i choose Active X instead, to which a VBA code on opening the workbook, would get the list which is refreshed based upon the user credentials.

Whats the best type of validation / drop down box to use, i know the usability changes Eg Font size but wanted advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Both have different usages and benefits. What is your use case?

Validation is limited in functionality but can offer a lot in many cases. It doesn't need explicit macro permissions.

VBA code will always require macro permissions etc.

If all you need is a drop down, use validation with named range. If you want further functionality, use VBA.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should suffice with what i am trying to do, all whom have the dash will have the correct permissions, its my first little project working with SQL and intertwining my VBA / Excel knowledge so quite exited in getting it up and running